# Is a differentiable convex function always smooth?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, convex-analysis

Are there any differentiable convex functions that are not smooth with parameter $L = 0$?

[image]

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to write maths. Also, what do you understand about the problem, what have you tried so far ?

Comment: A smooth function with parameter $L=0$ lies everywhere below it's tangent plane, so the only such convex functions should be affine ones.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you either mean concave, or convex with the inequality sign backwards.

For your question, consider the function
$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
x^2 & (x<0) \\
x^3 & (x\geq 0)
\end{cases}$$